# How many different ways to distribute 30 different books to 3 people, such that the number of books given to each of them create an arithmetic series?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different ways to distribute $30$ *different books* to $3$ people, such that the number of books given to each of them create an arithmetic series?

So, I thought one of them should have exactly $10$ books, and the others can partition rest of the books however they like.

Example: $1 - 10 - 19$

Choose $10$ books, $\binom{30}{10}$, any of them can have exactly $10$ books, so multiply it by $3$, also others can partition the books however they like, which is $2^{20}$.
In total $\binom{30}{10} \times 3 \times 2^{20}$.

Then, I guess I should be done here. Except, when all of them have $10$ books, so $10-10-10 $ right? Therefore I should discard $2 \times \binom{30}{10} \times \binom{20}{10}$.

In conclusion, $\ 3 \times 2^{20} \times \binom{30}{10} - (2 \times \binom{30}{10} \times \binom{20}{10})$

Is my answer true? If you have an another approach, can you share? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would have considered the constant sequence an arithmetic sequence as well, despite its triviality.  This, just like how a line can be considered a [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) and other such [degenerate cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)) for other definitions and objects in mathematics.  After all, a constant sequence does satisfy that the difference between terms is constant, just like any other arithmetic progression satisfies.

Comment: I already consider them as an arithmetic sequence. But we overcount them when we calculate it with $3 \times 2^{20} \times \binom{30}{10}$.

Comment: @bedirhan you are correct on that. I do not see anything wrong with your working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to treat the $10-10-10$ case completely separately from the rest. The number of ways out of $2^{20}$ for the other two people to get $10$ books is $\binom{20}{10}$. The number of ways to distribute the books equally is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{30}{10,10,10}=\binom{30}{20}\binom{20}{10}$. Thus the answer is $3\binom{30}{10}\left(2^{20}-\binom{20}{10}\right)+\binom{30}{10,10,10}$, which matches your answer.